# How to manually choose a driver for a device in Windows 10? (Device Manager is probably not the answer...)

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have a driver installed for an Apple V1 Trackpad (Magic Trackpad 1). (I grabbed a compatible one from a Bootcamp installation with https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier).

Windows automatically uses a default msmouse.inf to profile the Apple Trackpad V1 and uses an generic driver.
[Device Status in Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hM18.png)
[Device driver log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68RCC.png)

How can one specify the driver to use for a device? Device manager only lists generic ones, and trying to update the driver via "selecting the disk folder" just results in it saying that the AppleWTP64.inf and associated folder with all the other bits isn't compatible (I don't care I still want to use it).
[Device manager listing suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruAvE.png)
[The Trackpad driver folder with all the driver parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxnfo.png)

I installed the driver with the associated exe and see its files in C:\Windows\System32. Is there a way to choose it?
[Driver is installed in System32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXYvR.png)

So maybe in the end the Trackpad V1 won't work... but I still would like to know how to manually choose a driver. I haven't found any hints in the couple hours I've been at this, and I haven't had any luck with regedits for the device...

Comment: Why are you trying to force the machine to use a driver for a device you don't actually possess? An Apple trackpad is a long, long way from a generic Synaptic you get in many PC laptops.

Comment: To clarify, though not pertinent to the question, I am trying to use my Apple Wireless Track Pad V1 with Windows 10. It is supported via Bootcamp installations of Windows 10 because Apple provides drivers via a Bootcamp driver package, but I am trying to do it with a just Windows 10. V2 is supported via this project https://github.com/imbushuo/mac-precision-touchpad . I just happen to have a V1 I would like to use with my Hackintosh build.